# Variable date with a static timestamp when creating a form in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, ms-access

I am trying to amend some code in VB that creates a form in Access that will allow the user to enter any date into a form but will return counts as of midnight on those entered dates.

My current code:

```
    strBegDate = Format(Forms!frmMain!txtDateIn, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    strEndDate = Format(Forms!frmMain!txtDateOut, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

    strSelect = "SELECT DTS.DT, CUS.FACILITYID, CUS.FACILITYNAME, COUNT(DISTINCT CUS.INDIVIDUALID) COUNTOFINDIV  " & _
"FROM (select dt  from (select sysdate dt from dual)  model  " & _
"return updated rows  dimension by(dt)  measures (1 as dummy)  " & _
"rules  (dummy[FOR dt from TO_DATE(' " & strBegDate & " ')  TO  TO_DATE(' " & strEndDate & " ') INCREMENT 1] = null)) DTS  " & _
```

Any tips on how to amend my code to add a static midnight timestamp when a user enters any date.

Many thanks!

Comment: First format it correctly...

Comment: Oops, sorry. I just copied and pasted my code directly into my post without cleaning it up.

Comment: What SQL dialect do you want for the `SELECT` statement?  That is not close to valid Access SQL.

Comment: you should use Dates not strings for Dates.